# How to Debug in STMCubeIDE?

Tags: stm32cubeide, stm32cubemx, st-link

I am new to STM32. I have recently installed STM32CUBEIDE. I have written basic code . connected ST-Link v2 (STM8 & STM32) to my laptop and pressed F11 (to debug).
I get the following error

```
Error in initializing ST-LINK device.
Reason: ST-LINK firmware upgrade required. Please upgrade the ST-LINK firmware using the upgrade tool.
```

I get the following pop-ups.
[image]

After clicking yes.

ST link upgrade shows error as shown below
[image]

Now the version of st link upgrade is 3.37.
I manually downloaded St link upgrader of version V2.J36.S7
[image]

Here after manually upgrading the firmware of ST link I get the same error with the same reason. What I could gather is that latest version of ST link upgrader does not work with my
ST link dongle but to debug and upload code I need to upgrade it via STMCubeIDE but that does not happen.

If I missed something please guide me.
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: is it a fake Chinese st-link?

Comment: @0___________ I do not know. It looks like a dongle (pen drive) red color.

Comment: The it is Chinese fake. Use openOCD. It does not have reset line as well and its usability is very limited

Comment: openOCD is free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate the same problem a while a go. In my chase the debugger it self (st/linkv2) was broken and I tried to upload it with a other dongle and it worked fine. So it could be just be a broken dongle.